# Send 'User' name and 'Form content' in email notification

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-email

I'm trying to get the form to send an email notification of the 'Users' username and content of the 'Comment' its self. I have managed to get the title of the post working but nothing else. Need a little help.

**Views**

```
def ViewPost(request, slug):
        try:
            post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except BlogPost.DoesNotExist: 
            print("Blog with this slug does not exist")
            post = None
    
    
        comments = post.comments.filter(status=True)
        user_comment = None
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                user_comment.post = post
                user_comment.user = request.user
                user_comment.save()
               
                messages.success(request, ("Comment successfully posted, thank you..."))
                send_mail('You have recieved a comment on a blog post', post.title, post.user # not working , #reference comment here 
                [
                    'gmail.com'])
              
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
    
        
        return render(request, 'mhpapp/view-post.html', {'post': post, 'slug': slug, 'comments': user_comment, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

**Comment Model**

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="",)
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=100, default="")
    text = models.TextField('Comment',max_length=1000, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ("date",) 

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s -> %s'%(self.post.title, self.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your view function should be named `view_post` (follow snake case in Python code). Refer to [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) for Python coding conventions. It should just be doing that, i.e. viewing a post with given `slug`. Using `POST` method to actually post a comment on that post in the same view should be avoided. You can do that in another view, and once a comment is posted successfully, you can redirect to the same `slug` on your `view_post` view.

Now coming to the actual issue with your code, the call to `send_mail` function is wrong. A good practice to follow in your code is to pass the parameters as keyword arguments. In cases when the complexity of a function becomes high (due to the increasing number of parameters that it expects), it becomes easier for you and anyone else reading your code to understand what is happening, if you pass parameters as keyword arguments.

The [send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#send-mail) function expects the following parameters:

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
```

So, your function call will be changed to something like this:

```
subject = f"User: {user_comment.user.username} left you a comment"
message = f"Hi, {user_comment.user.username} left the following comment on post with slug {user_comment.post.slug}\n {user_comment.text}"
send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, from_email="youremail@example.com", recipient_list=['someone@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: I would possibly like to expand the conversation on the first part of advice you gave? Is there anyway to start a chat? of course if you are willing.

Comment: Hey, @DavidHenson I'm not sure if you can start a chat on SO, but I think I answered your newest question just now. Still, if you need to contact me, you'll find my email on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

The `message` parameter of [`send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) should be a string.

So try something like following and also use `fail_silently=False` so:

```py
# your existing code
# .....

# Send notification
message = f"UserName: {request.user.username} \n\n Comment: {user_comment.text}"
send_mail('You have received a comment on a blog post', message, 'your_email@example.com', ['gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```